# ggplot does not plot data in the given order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some date points:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  c1 = as.character(1:10),
  c2 = sample(seq(from=as.Date("2012-01-01"),to=as.Date("2012-12-01"),by="day"), 10)
)
df <- arrange(df,c2)
qplot(c2,c1,data=df) + scale_x_date(breaks="1 month")
```

Although I used *arrange* to sort the data, ggplot does not plot the data in order:
[image]

The expected plot is:

[image]

How do I tell ggplot to plot the c1 column in the given order rather than the natural sort order for the "character" type ?

SessionInfo():

```
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.7.1      ggplot2_0.9.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-0   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       grid_2.14.1        gtable_0.1.1       labeling_0.1      
 [7] MASS_7.3-16        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.4        proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1    
[13] scales_0.2.2       stringr_0.6.1      tools_2.14.1
```

dput(df):

```
structure(list(c1 = structure(c(8L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
10L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9"), class = "factor"), c2 = structure(c(15343, 15378, 
15416, 15508, 15543, 15547, 15548, 15551, 15558, 15625), class = "Date")), .Names = c("c1", 
"c2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you say what version of ggplot you're using (and perhaps some info from `sessionInfo()`?)

Comment: it shouldn't really be necessary, but can you give the results of `dput("df")` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. I'm running the same version of ggplot, and I don't see this behavior at all.

Comment: I just updated to latest plyr and ggplot with update.packages, I have the same issue :-(

Comment: The only other thing I can think of to try is to update R itself, since you're a few versions behind there too. Sorry!

Comment: I'm stumped too.  `arrange` shouldn't even matter, because `ggplot` should plot the points in date-sorted order anyway ...  There have been some recent updating issues with ggplot2 and plyr, as a last resort I would start a clean session and `install.packages(c("ggplot2","scales","plyr"))`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm updating R to see if I can reproduce the problem. I'll update my post when it's done...

Comment: A clean reinstall of all the packages did not solve the problem, I'm updating R itself...

Comment: adding the picture of the desired plot (how did you make it???) has made the question much clearer.

Comment: I set the levels manually:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There is no problem (with R).

You have been plotting a random permutation of dates against a character vector of digits that were coerced from integer. You are getting exactly what you asked for. No need to reinstall R or any packages. The dates in the 'c2' column will get sorted in the process of constructing the plot, so there is no need to pre-sort them and doings so will have no effect.

If on the the hand you want the the labels on the y axis to be the c1-values but the y-values to be the order-statistic (the integer order), then you need to plot 1:length(c1) against the date and change the default labels. (This remains a difficulty in your understanding of the expected behavior of a plotting process. There was no need to reinstall R.) This is the base graphics solution:

```
> with(df, plot(c2,1:10, yaxt="n"))
> axis(2, at=1:10, labels=df$c1)
```

I find the ggplot documentation rather frustrating. Try to find how to substitute axis labels is something that is just not apparent. I tried update_labels without success.  The use of a different language for plotting entities in that system remains an ongoing barrier for me. I know that many people have the opposite reaction and that ggplot2 is a favorite package for many. (Edit: this appears to create the desired plot in the ggplot world:)

```
> p <- qplot(c2, 1:nrow(df),data=df) + scale_x_date(breaks="1 month")
> p
> p + scale_y_discrete( labels=df$c1)
```

Comment: So how would you plot the c1 column ordered by date ? That's what I'm trying to do

Comment: That is what you are doing: plotting the c1 column ordered by date. It's apparently the case that you are expecting some different result, except you have not described your expectation in sufficient detail for people to pin down _your_ difficulties.

Comment: I added the plot I expect to produce. How do I tell ggplot to plot the c1 column with the order in the dataframe rather than the natural order for strings ?

Comment: Thanks for your very clear answer. To solve my problem, I decided to turn c1 into a factor after I use arrange: df$c1 = factor(df$c1,levels=df$c1,ordered=TRUE).